# Ajax form validation response

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, validation

When I am submitting form via Ajax, I have 2 ways of showing the user validation error messages:

1) If everything is ok `return Json(new { Status = true })`, if there are errors `return View(model)` in controller. And then on client side something like `if (response.Status == undefined) $("#formWrapper).html(response)` which will replace form with new one which contains error messages.

2) If everything is ok `return Json(new { Status = true })`, and if there are errors `return Json(new { Status = false, Errors = errorList })` and then on client side go through `errorList` and append messages to elements.

Which one should I choose?

Note: I know I have client side validation and request wont be submitted at all if there are errors, but there are some things that need to be checked on backend and cant be put in client side validation, so I need mechanism to return info about validation errors from controller.

Comment: Choose the second one all day long :) Maybe also instead of true and false, you can set a value like 1 and -1

Comment: Option 2 will be better performance, and not require the `$.validator` to be re-parsed

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the first one. You tend to avoid more bugs when you completely replace views, data, or just about anything instead of changing it.

The second one is basically changing the *state* of the view. Changing state is one of the biggest sources of bugs in programming.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with option two as you can get more information of the error in the client side (Other then just view) and display the perfect error message. Like user entered wrong or the data caused error or any custom one from the server side as you mentioned error list.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is different when you Success return

```
Json(new { Status = true })
```

and when catch any error Set Response.StatusCode with some types  to handle it in ajax error callback I always do that code below.

```
Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
return Json(result.ErrorMessage);
```

with this approach you will be seperated the concerns.